# make display:table fill out horizontal space without setting width

Tags: html, css, floating

I have some floats in 2 containers. The containers need to enclose the floats but maintain a minimum height of 100%, both of them (container>another container>floats).

I have tried minimum height but apparently minimum height needs a parent with exact height, not minimum. So it wont really work for both the containers, could only work on the outer one.

Display table with 100% height on the containers seems to do what i want, make them at least 100% tall but stretchable if the content is longer.

The Problem:

Display:table kills the width of the containers. I cant set width to 100%, because i need to define their width with margins later on. I need them to behave like normal divs, taking up all horizontal space available.

Is there a solution to my problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/Ka3TT/2/

My code:

```
<html>
    <body>
<div class="enclose2">
<div class="enclose1">
<div class="float">
Float<br>
Float<br>
Float<br>
Float<br>
Float<br>
Float<br>
Float<br>
Float<br>
Float<br>
Float<br>
Float<br>
Float<br>
Float<br>
Float<br>
Float<br>
Float<br>
Float<br>
Float<br>
Float<br>
Float<br>
Float<br>
Float<br>
Float<br>

</div>
<div class="float">Float</div>
    <div class="float">Float</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>​
```

My CSS:

```
.float {
    width:100px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    float:left;
}
.enclose1, .enclose2 {
 height:100%;
display:table;
    background-color:#ccc;
}    
body, html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what your margins are going to be later, kind of a shot in the dark without that info, but you might try using something like:

```
.float {
border:solid 1px black;
float:left;
height:100%;
width:29%;
margin-left:20px;
}
.enclose1, .enclose2 {
height:100%;
display:table;
background-color:#ccc;
width:100%;
}    
body, html {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

It keeps the three columns in line and expands them to the same height, while letting the divs expand horizontally to fill up the entire space available.   I am not sure exactly what your margins are going to be, if enclose divs are going to be inside a wrapper or what the full code will look like so you will have to play with the enclose1 & 2 width and .float width and margin to get the fit you are looking for.

NOTE: I might also be a little confused because you said you want them to take up all horizontal space available but have a fixed 100px width on the floats and don't want to set the enclose to 100% width - which I have done in the example, but the principle works with a fixed width and margin on enclose as well like so:

```
.float {
width:33%;
border:solid 1px black;
float:left;
}
.enclose1 {
height:100%;
display:table;
background-color:#bbb;
width:800px;
margin:50px;
}   

body, html {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.enclose2 {
height:100%;
background-color:#ccc;
display:table;
}
```

If its just the enclose classes that you want to expand horizontally with the floats having a fixed width of 100px, you can always put the whole thing in a wrapper with width:100% add padding and then set enclose to width 100% which will act the same way as putting margins on enclose but allow it to expand horizontally.

Sorry for the long winded answer but kind of depends on what the final goal is going to be.

Comment: basically i want the encloses to be 100% wide minus margins asigned on them. the floats will form a fixed-liquid-fixed layout. my problem is that table shrink wraps

Comment: :) great, glad you found the solution you were looking for

Answer (score 1):

If I get what you are trying to do. I would apply a `display: table-cell` to the float instead of floating it. This will make all of the blocks the same height regardless of the content.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/Ka3TT/4/

Might want to change the class name...

```
.float {
    width:100px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: i need to support older browsers as well so i cant go without floats

Comment: @user1721135 Sorry about that. I messed with a bunch of css but IE7 just won't cooperate. If you know of some certain css that will make it work just in IE7 then just add a "*" prefix to the attribute like "*height: 100%;"

Comment: my bad, display:table isnt supported at all in IE7 :/ i need to do the whole thing differently, using inline-block instead.